Error on kubernetes deployment using ingress with domain and tls
I was creating a deployment in kubernetes using ingress with domain and tls
my application is simple currency convertor which is using external api in the backend to convert the currency after the button pressed in frontend.
My deployment is working fine with load-balancer but when i add the domain and tls using ingress the application is giving 404 after clicking on button and when i use the path as / instead of custom path in path based routing it is working there but not with using path.
Here are the screenshot of working setup using / in path and ingress file screenshot also
working fine
ingress of working setup
screenshot of using with path /play
ingress file /play
output of /play
